# Microsoft Application Registration Portal vs Microsoft Azure Active Directory

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm reading the MS Graph SDK and I see two paths

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/

**Microsoft Application Registration Portal**: Register a new application that works with Microsoft Account and/or organizational accounts using the unified V2 Authentication Endpoint.

**Microsoft Azure Active Directory**: Register a new application in your tenant's Active Directory to support work or school users for your tenant or multiple tenants.

It seems like the first case would work in all situation? If that is the case why is there a need for the second case? Is the second case in case you were wanting to restrict access to only a certain tenant?

Answer (score 1):

You can now use the new [Azure Active Directory admin center](https://aad.portal.azure.com) in the Azure portal to register v2 apps.

The application registration portal is being deprecated as per the website: *"We will no longer support registering and managing converged and Azure AD applications here starting May 2019."*